# SQL Quotes failed query

Tags: mysql

I have a weird problem: I get this error;

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = 'aaaa'
AND expire >= '1387730046'' at line 1
```

You see 2 times ' on the end. But the SQL is;

```
"SELECT * FROM mails WHERE key = '".$mysql->real_escape_string($_GET['key'])."'
AND expire >= '".strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))."'"
```

So, I don't understand why I get this error. Does somebody know what I doing wrong?

Comment: Unusally for error messages, those produced by MySQL are rather informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word `key` is a reserved word in MySQL (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html)).  So you need to escape it:

```
SELECT * FROM mails WHERE `key` = '".$mysql->real_escape_string($_GET['key'])."' AND expire >= '".strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))."'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Query should be:

```
"SELECT * FROM mails WHERE `key` = '".$mysql->real_escape_string($_GET['key'])."' AND expire >= '".strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))."'"
```

always use parentesis around columns.